# How can I configure Spring Data to use the string version of an object when saving to Mongo DB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I've got an object that represents an Artefact:

```
public class Artifact {

    private final URI location;

    public Artifact(URI location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

When I use `MongoTemplate` to save this, the URI gets turned into an object:

```
{ "location" : { "scheme" : "http", "authority" : "localhost:8080", "host" : "localhost", "port" : 8080, "path" : "/testFrontendURL", "schemeSpecificPart" : "//localhost:8080/testFrontendURL", "hash" : 331612143, "string" : "http://localhost:8080/testFrontendURL" }
```

But, this could just be represented by the URI string:

```
{"location": "http://localhost:8080/testFrontendURL"}
```

How can I configure Spring Data to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own convertors

References:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html

[Spring data mongodb query converts String to ObjectId automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346028/spring-data-mongodb-query-converts-string-to-objectid-automatically)