# Springboot + mongodb convert String to Date

Tags: string, mongodb, spring-boot, date

I have the following request, two string of date in format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"

```
{  
    "dataS": "2021-07-22T03:00:00Z",
    "dataE": "2021-07-23T03:00:00Z",
}
```

and I need to transform this value into a Date format to build the following query

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("date").gte(dataS).lte(dataE));
```

The format of **the field "date" in MongoDB is ISODate** like that: { "date" : ISODate("2019-04-13T03:00:00.000+0000")}

I try 2 approachs

1. Using the String value, I have the following query. This query does not work.

   Query: { "date" : { "$gte" : "2021-07-22T03:00:00" , "$lte" :"2021-07-23T03:00:00"}, "isDeleted" : false }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
2. Transforming the String to the Data format, as follows I get only the TimeStamp

   DateFormat originalFormatData = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
   query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("date").gte(originalFormatData.parse(dataS)).lte(originalFormatData.parse(dataE)));

   Result: Query: { "date" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : 1626933600000 }, "$lte" : { "$date" : 1627019999000 } }, "isDeleted" : false }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }

**The final result that I would like** and that works for the query would be this:

```
 Query: { "date" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2021-07-22T03:00:00" }, "$lte" : { "$date" : "2021-07-23T03:00:00" } }, "isDeleted" : false }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
```

Can someone help me with parse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DateFormat#parse(String source)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) actually produces a `Date` object from a `String`. The [`DateFormat#format(Date date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) should be used to format the date into a String representation.

`parse` from Date Format's javadoc:

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date.
> The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

`format` from Date Format's javadoc:

> Formats a Date into a date/time string.

I think you need to format a `Date` into the desired format (thus use the `format` method).

I'm not seeing your request class code, but an idea: you can receive the `dataS` and `dataE` properties as `Date`s, instead of strings. And then call `DateFormat#format(Date date)` to get them as Strings in the desired format.

But before you go too far down that route, have a look at this answers:

[Spring data mongodb query converts String to ObjectId automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346028/spring-data-mongodb-query-converts-string-to-objectid-automatically)

[Jackson Mapper Serialize/Deserialize ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389198/jackson-mapper-serialize-deserialize-objectid)

I'm guessing that this can be solved by writing your own Jackson Serializer.

Comment: Thanks man, i don't' know what happened, but now working only using parse method by Date class